# How to change the font size of a single index for UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

The way to change the font size for a `UISegmentedControl` would be the following:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
[self.segment setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

How can I change the font size for a single index in a `UISegmentedControl`? Or even better, if the text doesn't fit in the `segment` (instead of "Above", it has "Abo...") the font size should be smaller so that it can fit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930758/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uisegmentedcontrol?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below code

```
for (UIView *v in [[[segment subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews]) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *label=(UILabel *) v ;
        lable.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that loop through the first index only? (`[[segment subviews] objectAtIndex:0]`)

Comment: [[segment subviews] objectAtIndex:0] Change objectAtIndex according to your tab index